Attribute error 'name' not fill in fdpf libary
Good morning/Afternoon/evening,
One of the interns from secondary school in my work. was tasked with completing an error report on an array of QGIS items.
He did it and it works very well on his computer.
Now I have the task of adding it to the project.
The code looks like this:
lass PDF(FPDF): # stopka z numerem strony
            def footer(self):
                self.set_y(-15)
                self.cell(0, 10, f'Strona {self.page_no()}', 0, 0, 'C')
        def create_pdf(filename):
            czas = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
            pdf = PDF()
            walidator_sciezka = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
            pdf.add_page()
            pdf.alias_nb_pages()
            pdf.set_margins(10,10,10)
            
            pdf.add_font('Verdana', '', walidator_sciezka + "/fpdf\Verdana.ttf", uni = True)
            pdf.add_font("Verdana", "B", walidator_sciezka + "/fpdf\Verdana-bold.ttf", uni = True)
            pdf.set_font('Verdana', 'B',14)
            pdf.cell(0,5,ln = 1)
            pdf.cell(0,0, "Raport z kontroli", align='C',ln=2)
            pdf.set_font("Verdana", "", 8)
            pdf.cell(0,5,ln = 1)
            pdf.cell(100,0, "wynik kontroli:", align = "R", ln = 0)
            print ('ustalony font i komórki')
            if len(bledyKontroli["KLASA"]) == 0:
                wynikkontroli = "Pozytywny"
                pdf.set_text_color(0,255,0)

            else:
                wynikkontroli = "Negatywny"
                pdf.set_text_color(255,0,0)
            lightblue = (143, 216, 255)
            gray = (220,220,220)
            pdf.cell(100,0,wynikkontroli, align = "L")
            pdf.cell(0,5,ln = 1)
            pdf.set_text_color(0,0,0)
            pdf.cell(100,0, "wynik walidacji:", align = "R", ln = 0)
            print ('ustalony font i komórki 2')
            if len(bledyWalidacji["WIERSZ"]) == 0:
                wynikw = "Pozytywny"
                pdf.set_text_color(0,255,0)
            else:
                wynikw = "Negatywny"
                pdf.set_text_color(255,0,0)
            pdf.cell(100,0,wynikw, align = "L")
            pdf.cell(0,5, ln = 1) # wolne miejsce
            pdf.set_text_color(0,0,0)
            pdf.cell(100,0,"data kontroli:", ln=0, align = "R") # tekst
            pdf.cell(100,0, czas , ln = 1, align = "L")
            pdf.cell(0,1,ln = 1)
            print ("ustawienie komórek")
            with pdf.table(first_row_as_headings = False, col_widths = (105,95), borders_layout = "NONE", v_align = "TOP") as tabelaskp:
                rzad = tabelaskp.row()
                rzad.cell("szablon kontroli:", align = "R", padding=(1,1,1,1))
                rzad.cell("skp", align = "J", padding = (1,40,1,1))
            pdf.cell(0,1,ln=1)
            
            # tabela walidacji
            if len(bledyWalidacji["WIERSZ"]) > 0:
                pdf.set_font("Verdana", "B", 14)
                pdf.cell(0,0,"Tabela z błędami walidacji", align = "C")
                pdf.set_font("Verdana",  "", 8)
                pdf.cell(0,5,ln = 1)
                pdf.set_fill_color(lightblue)
                with pdf.table(col_widths=(40,12,40,88), text_align = "J",padding = (1)) as table:

                    pdf.set_font("Verdana", "", 5)
                    headings = table.row()
                    
                    headings.cell("WALIDOWANY PLIK")
                    headings.cell("WIERSZ")
                    headings.cell("OPIS BŁĘDU")
                    headings.cell("KOMUNIKAT BŁĘDU")
                    pdf.set_fill_color(gray)
                with pdf.table(datawalidacja, col_widths=(40,12,40,88), first_row_as_headings = False, text_align = "J", padding = (1)):
                    pass
                pdf.set_fill_color(255,255,255)
                pdf.set_font("Verdana", "" , 6)
            else: # jak nie ma błędów walidacji
                pdf.set_font("Verdana", "", 14)
                pdf.cell(0,0, "Nie znaleziono błędów walidacji", align = "C")
            
            pdf.cell(w=0,h=10,txt = " ",ln=1)
            # tabela konotroli
            if len(bledyKontroli["KLASA"]) > 0:
                pdf.set_font("Verdana", "B", 14)
                pdf.cell(0,0,"Tabela z błędami kontroli", align="C")
                pdf.set_font("Verdana", "", 5)
                pdf.cell(0,5,ln = 1)
                pdf.set_fill_color(lightblue)
                with pdf.table(col_widths=(40,20,50,70), text_align = "J", padding = (1)) as table1:
                    headings = table1.row()
                    headings.cell("KONTROLOWANY PLIK")
                    headings.cell("KLASA")
                    headings.cell("LOKALNY ID")
                    headings.cell("KOMUNIKAT BŁĘDU")
                    pdf.set_fill_color(gray)
                with pdf.table(datakontrola, col_widths=(40,20,50,70), first_row_as_headings = False, text_align="J", padding = (1)):
                    pass
            else:
                pdf.set_font("Verdana", "B", 14)
                pdf.cell(0,0,"Nie znaleziono błędów kontroli", align = "C")
                pdf.set_font("Verdana", "", 5)

            pdf.output(filename)
        create_pdf(pdfpath)

however, in the last line I get an error relating to... another one of the internal files of the fpdf library.
The full error is:
File "[full path]", line 473, in validationIControlaAttributes -> main file name
create_pdf(pdfpath)
File "[full path]\validatorFilesGML.py", line 472, in create_pdf
pdf.output(filename)
File "[full path]\Validator_plikow_gml\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 5014, in output
self.buffer = output_producer.bufferize()
File "[full path]\gml_validator\fpdf\output.py", line 380, in bufferize
font_objs_per_index = self._add_fonts()
File "[full path]\Validator_plikow_gml\fpdf\output.py", line 549, in _add_fonts
print(f"Font name for TTF: {font.name}")
AttributeError: name

TTF comes from the line: pdf.add_font('Verdana', '', validator_path + "/fpdf\Verdana.ttf", uni = True) it is a separate file storing the Verdana font (validator_path is a variable storing the path to the folder). As I checked with prints, the name attribute is possible for the font variable in the output.py file (the code is provided at the end), but it is not filled.
...and in general, is it worth changing/going deeper into the fpdf library, instead of going around it?
The assembly of output.py is as follows:
def _add_fonts(self):
    font_objs_per_index = {}
    for font in sorted(self.fpdf.fonts.values(), key=lambda font: font.i):
        # Standard font
        print("Dostępne atrybuty dla font:", dir(font), 'wartosci',self.fpdf.fonts.values(),'fonty' ,self.fpdf.fonts) # dir wykazał że metoda .name jest możliwa,m zaś kolejne dwie wartości wyglądają tak: wartosci dict_values([TTFFont(i=1, fontkey=verdana), TTFFont(i=2, fontkey=verdanaB)]) fonty {'verdana': TTFFont(i=1, fontkey=verdana), 'verdanaB': TTFFont(i=2, fontkey=verdanaB)}
        if font.type == "core":
            encoding = (
                "WinAnsiEncoding"
                if font.name not in ("Symbol", "ZapfDingbats")
                else None
            )
            core_font_obj = PDFFont(
                subtype="Type1", base_font=font.name, encoding=encoding
            )

            self._add_pdf_obj(core_font_obj, "fonts")
            font_objs_per_index[font.i] = core_font_obj
        elif font.type == "TTF":
                fontname = f"MPDFAA+{font.name}"  #Here I gain error

Of course you need to know fpdf to find the source of the problems- why TTF file (with verdana Font) didn't fill the name attribute.
Thank you in advance for any help!
